# X and Y axis plot date

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am unable to get data points on my graph. Both axis are zoomable and both are date ranges. More specifically, the x axis is the date and the y axis is the hour. I am wondering if it is something with my JSON file formatting with the hours but I am still unsure of why it is not plotting anything. An example of my JSON file is

```
data = [ 
{ "date" : "2013-21-02T00:00:00",
  "vertical" : "2013-20-02T11:00:00"
},...]
```

Below is my code:

```
//Define the min and max date 
   var mindate = new Date(2013,02,20),  // TODO: clip date  
       maxdate = new Date(2013,02,26);

//Define the range of hours for the yaxis. Uses military time. 
var ymindate = new Date(2013,02,20, 7),  // TODO: clip date 
    ymaxdate = new Date(2013,02,20, 17);

margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 45};
width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right;
height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .domain([mindate, maxdate])
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.time.scale()
    .domain([ymindate, ymaxdate])
    .range([height, 0]);

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function (d) { return d.date; })
    .y(function (d) { return d.vertical; });

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
     .x(x)
    .y(y)
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

svg = d3.select('#chart')
    .append("svg:svg")
    .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .call(zoom)
    .append("svg:g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var make_x_axis = function () {
    return d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom")
        .ticks(5);
};

var make_y_axis = function () {
    return d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left")
        .ticks(5);
};

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(5);

svg.append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(5);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x grid")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(make_x_axis()
    .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
    .tickFormat(""));

 svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y grid")
    .call(make_y_axis()
    .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
   .tickFormat(""));

var clip = svg.append("svg:clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("svg:rect")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var chartBody = svg.append("g")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");

chartBody.append("svg:path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line);

 function zoomed() {
    svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
    svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
    svg.select(".x.grid")
         .call(make_x_axis()
         .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
         .tickFormat(""));
     svg.select(".y.grid")
         .call(make_y_axis()
         .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
         .tickFormat(""));
    svg.select(".line")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", line);
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that you'll need to do is to parse your data into a format that's recognised by D3.  So something like:

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%d-%mT%H:%M:%S").parse; //Note the T in the middle

data.forEach(function (d,i) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.vertical= parseDate(d.vertical);
})
```

From there just throw it at the line function and I *think* it should all work out.  Oh the API reference is pretty helpful on this, where is [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting).

I've just edited the code block above by changing *value* to *vertical* and including the final closing bracket (oops).

The next thing is the line generator was set to simply return the *date* or *vertical* value, so it needs to be changed to:

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function (d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function (d) { return y(d.vertical); });
```

Note the inclusion of the `x(...)` and `y(...)`.

And here's a link to a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/juXZM/)

Comment: When I try your suggestion, I am getting errors from the d3.js file. When the y axis is an integer and the x axis is a date, it works. So, I don't think parsing is the problem. When both axis are dates, the graph will not plot.

Comment: I've made some edits to earlier post and cleaned the code up a bit as indicated.  You also need to look at the line generator as discussed above.